# How can I seperate service on the server?

Tags: apache, service, web-deployment

I have two services i.e. jsf web app service and android service. Both are using the same functionality like login registration etc.

Now I have to separate both the services because I have used all the functionality in web app that same functionality I want to use it for android app..
So how can I deploy it on the server?

Like on the apache server in webapp folder there will be two subfolders webapp/android and webapp/webapp so where can I store all the *.java files(Which contains the login and communicate with database) on the server so that both of them can access the existing functionality.

Thanks